# git push heroku master permission denied on VISTA

Tags: git, ssh, github, heroku, public-key

(Using Vista)I'm trying to clone an app from my GitHub Repository and push it into Heroku. Okay, so I've tried to create an SSH key so many times with this:

```
 `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
```

It seems to go perfectly. I have it on my C:/Users/***/.ssh folder. I now try to clone an app i forked in GitHub. When I try to clone it on the rails_apps directory, I get a message saying

```
 Permission Denied(public key).
```

I found a solution on the net saying that I should run this first:

```
`ssh-add`
```

So I tried doing that. But it said that:

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Then after some googling I find something about executing the ssh-agent. So I do this:

```
`ssh-agent bash`
```

and the command line changes from my rails_apps directory to this:

```
`bash3.1$>`
```

So I run:

```
`bash3.1$>ssh-add [path to .ssh folder]`
```

and it successfully adds the rsa private key(it doesn't work with id-rsa.pub). I have also pasted the newly generated public key to my GitHub account.

Now when I try to clone:

```
`bash3.1$>git clone git@github.com:username/myrepo.git`
```

It now successfully clones the repo I forked in GitHub. Now that I have the app in my local repo, I try to create a heroku app.

```
`bash3.1$>cd myrepo`  
`bash3.1$>heroku create myapp`
```

And this code runs successfully. Git remote added successfully. Now all I have to do is to push it.

```
`bash3.1$>git push heroku master`
```

BAM! I get the error message again.

`Permission denied (public key)`

I am so close into pushing my app to heroku. But it just won't work. Can you help me. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks! :D

Comment: What the `git remote -v show` command displayed in your cloned repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: your [ticket on GitHub Support](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2048-cant-git-push-to-heroku-permission-denied-help) prompted the answer:

> You need to give heroku your key. There should be a command to do it. If you can't find it, you'll have to contact their support.

For that, see [Graeme Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579626/graeme-collins)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722023/6309) (and also [Heroku error: "Permission denied (public key)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481973/heroku-error-permission-denied-public-key) ):

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

See [Heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) for more on that process.
You can then see a list of all keys, including the key’s name, like this:

```
heroku keys
```

Note: that suppose you didn't use sudo to generate your keys, as " [git clone heroku ssh permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591084/git-clone-heroku-ssh-permission-denied) " illustrates (where `heroku keys:add` doesn't work)

---

More information about your ssh keys in your other [GitHub Support ticket](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2046-ssh-key-public-key-denied-please-help-me).

```
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
```

> I'm not sure why it would be looking at `/.ssh` and not `~/.ssh` then.
>   Try moving your keypair over to that path.

---

Shouldn't that be:

```
 git push origin master
```

? By default, a reference to the cloned repo is called 'origin', not 'heroku'

What does

```
git remote -v show
```

display?

It you want, you can reference the distant repo by the heroku name

```
git remote add heroku git@github.com:git_username/projectname.git
```

Comment: Thanks Von. I tried what you said changing heroku to origin. It didn't work as well. I tried the command you said. Now when I

`git push heroku master`

It says

Everything up-to-date

But the app is still not on heroku. I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 61):

I had a similar problem.
Running the following command fixed it for me:

`heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Substitute "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" with your path to your id_rsa.pub file.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the correct answer. I knew I had changed my keys and was just looking for the command to update them :)

Comment: There's a nice little tutorial on it here
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:deploying

Answer (score 1):

The following line solved the problem for me.

```
heroku accounts:set youraccount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can login first in heroku providing Enail and Password and can follow the following steps to add a local git repository into a heroku application instance.

1. Issue this command at the Git Bash $ ssh-keygen -t rsa (default location and with empty passphrase. You can alternatives too).
2. Again issue at the bash $ heroku keys:add (It will automatically add the public key from the default location).
3. Issu this at the bash to check keys. $ heroku keys .
4. You can add the remote for you app name $ heroku git:remote -a app_name
5. Now you can push the git repo to the heroku using this command $ heroku push origin master