# Can't push to heroku from second computer

Tags: git, heroku

I have two computers for development, both sync my development directory using dropbox so my directories are exactly the same no matter which computer I use.  When I use the first computer, I can push to heroku using "git push heroku master" and everything works fine.  However, when I go to the second computer, I receive an access denied error.

How do I authorize the second computer to push to the heroku website?

Comment: check the ssh key if you use ssh

Comment: is that something I should sync using dropbox?

Comment: I'm not sure about heroku, but some git server require a ssh key to make a secure connection.(cf: github)

Comment: Did you `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1824966/6309?

Answer (score 1):

You need to auth with heroku:

```
heroku auth:login
```

and go from there.